# Inconsistent behavior for image animation when changing window/frame state

Tags: image-mode

I've noticed that image animation produces strangely inconsistent behavior when changing window or frame state, depending on which command was most recently used to display or redisplay the image.

Steps to replicate:

1. Open Emacs 29.1 with no config (`emacs -Q`). I haven't tested this on other versions.
2. Visit an animated image file ([example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/132C_trans.gif)).
3. Evaluate `(setq image-animate-loop t)`.
4. If the animation is not running, do `image-toggle-animation` (`RET`). Then run any of the following commands: `toggle-frame-maximized`, `toggle-frame-fullscreen`, or `delete-other-windows` (the latter only if there are other windows open). RESULT: the animation stops.
5. Run any of the following commands: `image-transform-fit-to-window`, `image-transform-fit-both`, or `(find-alternate-file (buffer-file-name))` (i.e. (`C-x C-v RET`), then repeat step 4. RESULT: The animation stops as before.
6. Run any of the following commands: `image-increase-size`, `image-decrease-size`, `set-scale`, `image-transform-fit-to-width`, or `image-transform-fit-to-height`, then repeat step 4. RESULT: The animation *does not stop*, but keeps running.

I've looked at the definitions for these commands in image-mode.el and image.el, and I don't see anything obvious that would cause this discrepancy. For example, `image-transform-fit-to-width` and `image-transform-fit-to-height` give different results from `image-transform-fit-both` and `image-transform-fit-window`, but all of those commands work by simply setting the variable `image-transform-resize` followed by a call to `image-toggle-display-image`. What could be the  cause of this behavior?